# QED placement with `prooftree` package

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am using [Paul Taylor’s `prooftree` package](http://www.paultaylor.eu/proofs/) to typeset natural-deduction proof trees.

When a proof ends with a proof tree, how can one obtain the correct placement for the QED symbol?  For instance the MWE below, by placing `\qedhere` at the end and beginning of any of the last three lines before `\end{proof}`, and varying the order of the `\using` and `\justifies` commands, I was able to obtain all the following placements for the QED mark:

- horizontally flush to right margin, but *below* end of proof tree (as with no `\qedhere`);
- horizontally flush to right margin, but vertically aligned to *middle* of proof tree;
- *in* last line of proof tree, immediately adjacent to end of last formula;
- in last line of proof tree, immediately adjacent to *beginning* of last formula.

but not the desired one

- vertically, flush with last line of proof tree; horizontally, flush to right margin.

Has anyone encountered/solved similar problems?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{prooftree}
\begin{document}

  \begin{theorem}
  Equality is transitive.
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{proof}
    \[
    \begin{prooftree}
      \[
      \justifies \thickness=0.08em
      t = t
      \using{\scriptstyle{refl}}
      \]
      \qquad
      t = s
      \using{\scriptstyle{subst}}
      \justifies \thickness=0.08em
      s = t
    \end{prooftree}
    \]
  \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have the `prooftree` package. Have you tried `\qedhere` just before closing the last displayed equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a `bprooftree` environment that sets the reference point of the proof tree at the bottom rather than at the center.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{prooftree,adjustbox}

\newenvironment{bprooftree}
 {\begin{adjustbox}{raise=\depth}\begin{prooftree}}
 {\end{prooftree}\end{adjustbox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Equality is transitive.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
\[
\begin{bprooftree}
  \[
  \justifies \thickness=0.08em
  t = t
  \using{\scriptstyle\mathit{refl}}
  \]
  \qquad
  t = s
  \using{\scriptstyle\mathit{subst}}
  \justifies \thickness=0.08em
  s = t
\end{bprooftree}
\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]